# How to properly implement Quartz.Net job lifecycle for long running processes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, application-pool, quartz.net-2.0

I am using Quartz.Net to implement some asynchronous processing within the IIS worker process (IIS 8.5). One particular job may take more 10 minutes to run and does a lot of processing.

The following pieces of code illustrate how I am handling job life cycle.

**Schedule definition**

```
public class JobScheduler
{
    private static IScheduler _quartzScheduler;

    public static void Start()
    {
        _quartzScheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();
        _quartzScheduler.JobFactory = new NinjectJobFactory();

        ScheduleTheJob(_quartzScheduler);

        _quartzScheduler.Context.Add("key", "scheduler");
        _quartzScheduler.Start();
    }

    private static void ScheduleTheJob(IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<JobClass>().UsingJobData("JobKey", "JobValue").Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("JobTrigger", "JobGroup").UsingJobData("JobKey", "JobTrigger").StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                // 30 minutes for refresh period
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(ConfigService.JobRefreshPeriod)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }

    public static void StopScheduler(bool waitForCompletion)
    {
        _quartzScheduler.Shutdown(waitForCompletion);
    }
}
```

**Application pool shutdown handling**

```
public class ApplicationPoolService : IApplicationPoolService
{
    public bool IsShuttingDown()
    {
        return System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason != ApplicationShutdownReason.None;
    }

    public ApplicationShutdownReason GetShutdownReason()
    {
        return System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason;
    }
}

public class HostingEnvironmentRegisteredObject : IRegisteredObject
{
    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        if (immediate)
            return;

        JobScheduler.StopScheduler(waitForCompletion: true);

        var logger = NinjectWebCommon.Kernel.Get<ILoggingService>();
        var appPoolService = NinjectWebCommon.Kernel.Get<IApplicationPoolService>();
        var reason = appPoolService.GetShutdownReason().ToString();
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, $"HostingEnvironmentRegisteredObject.stop called with shutdown reason {reason}");
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs wiring up**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    JobScheduler.Start();

    HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(new HostingEnvironmentRegisteredObject());
}

protected void Application_Error()
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Logger.Log(LogLevel.Fatal, exception, "Application global error");
}

protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // stopping is now triggered in HostingEnvironmentRegisteredObject 
    // JobScheduler.StopScheduler(false);

    // get shutdown reason
    var appPoolService = NinjectWebCommon.Kernel.Get<IApplicationPoolService>();
    var reason = appPoolService.GetShutdownReason().ToString();
    Logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, $"Application_End called with shutdown reason {reason}");
}
```

**Job step description**

```
if (ApplicationPoolService.IsShuttingDown())
{
    Logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "(RefreshEnvironmentImportingSystemData) Application pool is shutting down");
    return;
}

// about 20-30 steps may be here
environments.ForEach(env => 
{
    if (ApplicationPoolService.IsShuttingDown())
         return;

    // do heavy processing for about 2 minutes (worst case), typically some 10-20s
}

// one job step may allocate several hundreds of MB, so GC is called to reclaim some memory sooner 
// it takes a few seconds (worst case)
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
GC.Collect();
```

Initially, I was stopping the scheduler when `Application_End` was called, but I realized that was called when application pool was about to be killed, so I move it when application pool was notified that its shutdown has been started.

I have left application pool with its default value for Shutdown time limit (90 seconds).

Job is configured to not allow concurrent executions.

**I want to achieve the following:**

- avoid forced killing of job during actual execution
- minimize the time when two worker processes run in the same time (shutting down one in parallel with the one just started to handle new requests)

**Question:** did I manage correctly the scheduled jobs or can I make improvements?